# How to append Ember.View Properly

Tags: ember.js

I have recently decided to do a major upgrade with my javascript libraries and have ran into a perplexing issue with appending Ember.Views. I have been researching this issue for several hours now and have tried many things but nothing has worked.

What I want to do is quite simple: Extend Ember.View, manually create a new instance of this extended view and then append it to a div. In a much earlier version (ember.js 1.5) this was extremely straightforward. Now (ember.js 1.9) attempting the same thing results in an error.

> Container was not found when looking up a views template. This is most
>   likely due to manually instantiating an Ember.View. See:
>   http://git.io/EKPpnA

Here is a very simple example that demonstrates this: http://jsfiddle.net/81dhm3ta/

**html**

```
<body>
    <script data-template-name="main" type="text/x-handlebars">
        Main
    </script>
    <div id="main" style="text-align: center;"></div>
</body>
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    App = Ember.Application.create();
    App.MainView = Ember.View.extend({
        templateName: 'main',
    });
    App.view = App.MainView.create();
    App.view.appendTo("#main");
});
```

Can someone show me the simplest way to do this properly?

Comment: Looks like you are fighting your way against Ember instead of letting him guide you. Why do you need to use the `ready` event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`App.view` is neither a D0M element or jQuery object that you can simply append to a div. It is an Ember object of type View.

In the link given by the error, you are clearly told that you **can't** create views like you did in your snippet. Dynamic views must be instantiated within a parent view or directly through the container (not recommended).

Your life will be much easier if you add views within a template by just using the `view` helper:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{view 'main'}}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Could you provide a full example of how to do this? I have been following the ember guide which doesn't show any of this. http://emberjs.com/guides/views/defining-a-view/

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to play around with this. I'm not a webdev by trade and am not even working on a traditional website so I just got this working previous and obviously I was doing it a very hacky way. Cheers!